# Magento 2: Current category not found

Tags: magento2, category

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
```

I have a debug got the null value

Comment: where are you calling this code?

Comment: Under the plugin folder call the Current category function @PhilippSander

Comment: Any option for category on/off

Comment: Category page is working but category search page is not working. When i debugged then got the error in code current category null. @PhilippSander

Comment: plugin for what file/method?

Comment: Plugin/ListProductPlugin.Php @PhilippSander

Comment: why don't you use $subject->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89917/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-philipp-sander).

Comment: `current_category`  should not work at Search page as it does not depend on category.Search  page collection depends on entire product collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead the object manager:

```
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}
```

Then you call it like this :

```
$category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');

$categoryId = $category->getId();

\Zend_Debug::dump($categoryId);
```

Comment: I have called same function. got the null value.

Comment: Just a different (and correct) way of doing the same thing but doesn't answer the question.